# Android: How to load image into Bitmap

Tags: android, image, load, bitmap, sd-card

I am able to load a resource image, from drawable folder, into a bitmap and even scale fine, however now I have a need to load an image from any stored on the SD-Card and I can see this will allow me to view and select;

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
```

However so far I have been unable to find out exactly what data is returned and how to load it into a bitmap.

UPDATED:

This is now what I got;

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    Uri contentURI =  Uri.parse(intent.getDataString());

    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    tempCanvas.setBitmap(mDrawing);

    Bitmap tempBitmap = null;

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try {           
      InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(contentURI);
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inSampleSize=8;
      tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
        }
    catch (Exception ee) {
      tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icon);
        }

    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    c.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
  }
}
```

And it errors out with "app has stopped unexpectedly" with logcat showing;

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/185 }} to activity {com.example.colorbook/com.example.colorbook.Colorbook}: java.lang.NullPointerException


Complete logcat as it finished gallery view activity and tried to return intent;<br>
02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onPause]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): store mCurrentPosition_backup=0<br>02-03 10:47:22.042: DEBUG/DisplayManager(22984): store mCurrentPosition_backup=0<br>02-03 10:47:22.092: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1459 objects / 91880 bytes in 44ms<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: INFO/AlbumMapper(22984): Create thumbnail for: /mnt/sdcard/workspace/Colorbook/res/drawable/fileload.png<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #37, /mnt/sdcard/workspace/Colorbook/res/drawable/fileload.png<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Raise getter prefetcher thread priority to normal.<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Join getter prefetch thread<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AbstractViewGetter(22984): Getter prefetch join time: 2<br>02-03 10:47:22.102: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(24768): Shutting down VM<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: WARN/dalvikvm(24768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/185 }} to activity {com.example.colorbook/com.example.colorbook.Colorbook}: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3734)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at com.example.colorbook.Colorbook.loadImageToCanvas(Colorbook.java:524)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at com.example.colorbook.Colorbook.onActivityResult(Colorbook.java:231)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)<br>02-03 10:47:22.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768):     ... 11 more<br>02-03 10:47:22.202: WARN/ActivityManager(97):   Force finishing activity com.example.colorbook/.Colorbook<br>02-03 10:47:22.704: WARN/ActivityManager(97): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{46207010 com.example.colorbook/.Colorbook}<br>02-03 10:47:22.742: DEBUG/Sensors(97): close_akm, fd=114<br>02-03 10:47:22.852: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onStop]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.902: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 398 objects / 23264 bytes in 38ms<br>02-03 10:47:22.902: DEBUG/MainActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][MainActivity][onDestroy]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: com.htc.album.MainActivity@46075ec0context size: 0<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: No more clients. release resources.<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/OnlineDataCenter(22984): [HTCAlbum][OnlineDataCenter][unbindContext]: End 0<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #-1, Decode Complete!!<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumMapper(22984): cancel current decode operation<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/ThumbnailWorker(22984): [stopWorking] Stop working, now join #-1, Decode Complete!!<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): set thread priority to normal<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): Join worker thread in destroy<br>02-03 10:47:22.912: DEBUG/AlbumAdapter(22984): Join time: 0<br>02-03 10:47:22.922: INFO/MainActivity(22984): mWorker finishes jobs at onDestroy().<br>02-03 10:47:22.932: DEBUG/CollectionsActivity(22984): [HTCAlbum][CollectionsActivity][onDestroy]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.932: DEBUG/AlbColAdap(22984): [HTCAlbum][AlbumCollectionsAdapter][onDestroy]: Begin<br>02-03 10:47:22.942: INFO/BatteryStatsImpl(97): notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked: 2->3<br>02-03 10:47:22.952: DEBUG/AlbColAdap(22984): [HTCAlbum][AlbumCollectionsAdapter][onDestroy]: End<br>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use this intent:

```
myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

And later on use this to get the image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode){
    case IMAGE_UPLOAD: //this is a constant, in your case I think it should be '1'
        if(imageReturnedIntent != null){// e.g. "back" pressed"
            Uri contentURI = Uri.parse(imageReturnedIntent.getDataString());        
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(contentURI);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=8;
            Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
       }
    break;

}
```

I'm sending that string around a bit, but in the end this is what happens:

there you are with , in this case, a thumb of the image. If you want it bigger, use a different samplesize :)

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch for the fast reply, but excuse me if this seems like a ignorant question, keep in my in am fairly new to both Java and Android, but what is the cr in; InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(contentURI);

Comment: I've used this, also because I needed the stream, but what it does is create a stream from the "uri" (just as you might do with a web-URI), and then create a bitmap from that stream. Read this for a basic intro in streams: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: Thanks I meant specifically "cr" which I figured needed to coded like this; ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

Comment: Ow, my bad! that was just an artifact of me removing all sorts of unneccesairy stuff from the code. I'll clarify

Comment: There you are, it's the contentresolver that was missing indeed, so your code looks right :)

Comment: Well thanks, however I am getting an "application has stopped unexpectedly" error, in  logcat shows; ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/185 }} to activity {com.example.colorbook/com.example.colorbook.Colorbook}: java.lang.NullPointerException. Perhaps reason is that I am trying to actually load the image in the onActivityResult section, where I see you have separated it out.

Comment: I am editing my original question now to show what I got in onActivityResult

Comment: Shouldn't matter, I'm sending that string to another activity with an intent/bundle and then basically doing this. Did you see that i'm using `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?

Comment: I've merged the 2 parts of the code, I don't see why it wouldn't work like this :)

Comment: I need a bigger part of the error log for that, but i think this is another issue. I can see that there is an uri in your result, but it can't be delivered. Dunno what colorbook is (your activity?)

Comment: Yeah colorbook is my activity. And yes you're right this is something else causing this error, as I know I can load an image from drawable folder fine in the onActivityResult, when clicking a simple button from another activity, but I got the exact same error when using the startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),1); even though I am not actually processing the intent data, but still only try to load my drawable resource. I will add larger part of error in my original question

Comment: If it is something else, and not the capturing of the returned data (URI) as a bitmap, you might want to start a new question for that problem? Otherwise This discussion and the answer will be very strange :)

Comment: Will do just that, starty new thread. Once that is solved, hopefully, I will be able to confirm and acknowledge your answer. Thanks a BUNCH!

Comment: Don't forget to mark what in your code this line is: Colorbook.java:524

Comment: Good suggestion. As soon as I found out how to turn on line numbers in Eclipse

Comment: For some reason when I load the actual image into bitmap and push it to Surfaceview, AFTER I exit onActivityResult, image loads fine!?!

Comment: Solution to get rid of error, was to draw the bitmap during SurfaceChanged, using a flag whether to load image.

Comment: Apparently SurfaceView is not ready to be drawn upon at that time, immediately after the MediaStore activity is returning selection

Comment: I am working on a very similar issue.  Does anyone know how to prevent picasa images from being displayed in the gallery.  They are not stored locally so they can not be gotten from the MediaStore.

Comment: I think you might want to open a separate question for that :)

Answer (score 1):

The data that is returned is the Uri of the image that was selected, you will still need to load the image. In your onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     ...some code to make sure the result is valid
     Uri imageUri = data.getData();
     imageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
}
```

And also you will have to use EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI vs INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.
This also loads the image on the UI thread which you probably won't want to do. You'll want to pass it off to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[]  data = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, uri, data, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```