# Android: Storing a reference of an image

Tags: java, android

I've asked a similar question a few days ago and want to precise it now:

I want to display the same image again and again and dont want to reload it everytime to speed up the app.

To keep it simple and to unterstand my problem I just created the example below:

```
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

     imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.myImage);
}
```

I'm loading my image 'myImage' 1000 times and prefere to load it once and then just display it by it's reference.

Is there a way to store a reference of an image in a variable ? Or must I cache the image somehow ?

Has anyone an idea how to manage this ?

Comment: are you using a listview first thing ?

Comment: No, I just do it like the example above. Is it necessary ?

Comment: No not at all. why dont you give glide library a try https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: The simplest solution would just be to use Glide. It will run faster and do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use advices from this article https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html.

Or use one of libraries for managing images (e.g. Picasso). It will do caching, resizing etc. instead of you. This is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

It used bitmap as follows code

```
Bitmap bitmap=null;
File f= new File(_path);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

[Android: How to load image into Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887297/android-how-to-load-image-into-bitmap)

Images come in all shapes and sizes. In many cases they are larger than required for a typical application user interface. Let reference

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You can store your image into a `Bitmap` static object and the call [setImageBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) whenever you need.

To load your drawable into a Bitmap, you can use the following code:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.myImage);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Is there a way to find out how long it takes android to display the image and how long the image is then displayed ? Just to compare the performance...

Comment: You can use Android Monitor to measure performance, i.e. CPU and Memory usage etc. Also, in a crudely way, you can print a timestamp right before and right after your loop where you print your image, using a static and a non-static Bitmap and then compare the results.

Comment: Okay, I try it out. Just for unterstanding the difference between static and non-static Bitmaps: My example above uses non-static Bitmaps, your code above uses a static Bitmap ?

Comment: No, my code only shows how to load a drawable into a Bitmap, to make it static you must declare static Bitmap b = ... Make it as a class variable

Answer (score -1):

### ImageView.setImageResource(int id)

```
public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
    // The resource configuration may have changed, so we should always
    // try to load the resource even if the resId hasn't changed.
    final int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
    final int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

    updateDrawable(null);
    mResource = resId;
    mUri = null;

    resolveUri();

    if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
        requestLayout();
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

And `resolveUri()`:

```
private void resolveUri() {
    if (mDrawable != null) {
        return;
    }

    Resources rsrc = getResources();
    if (rsrc == null) {
        return;
    }

    Drawable d = null;

    if (mResource != 0) {
        try {
            d = mContext.getDrawable(mResource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("ImageView", "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
            // Don't try again.
            mUri = null;
        }
    } else if (mUri != null) {
        String scheme = mUri.getScheme();
        if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE.equals(scheme)) {
            try {
                // Load drawable through Resources, to get the source density information
                ContentResolver.OpenResourceIdResult r =
                        mContext.getContentResolver().getResourceId(mUri);
                d = r.r.getDrawable(r.id, mContext.getTheme());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("ImageView", "Unable to open content: " + mUri, e);
            }
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(scheme)
                || ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(scheme)) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            try {
                stream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
                d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("ImageView", "Unable to open content: " + mUri, e);
            } finally {
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w("ImageView", "Unable to close content: " + mUri, e);
                    }
                }
            }
    } else {
            d = Drawable.createFromPath(mUri.toString());
        }

        if (d == null) {
            System.out.println("resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: " + mUri);
            // Don't try again.
            mUri = null;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }

    updateDrawable(d);
}
```

In fact when you load same image over and over time ,`resolveUri()` will waste lots of time .So you can store a `Drawable` object.

```
 context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
```